# Returning to command prompt after piping output to Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, command-line, sublime-text-2

I am running Sublime Text 2 and OS X 10.7.5. Frequently, I will run a command from the Terminal and redirect the output so I can view it in Sublime. For example:

```
svn diff | subl
```

When I do this, I can see the output in Sublime, but I don't see the command prompt until I either close the output or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This is somewhat annoying. I would like the command prompt to come up immediately, like it does when piping output to TextWrangler. How can I do this? I am sure I can come up with a shell script or Python script to do it for me, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way, maybe involving some option built into Sublime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell the shell to *background the process* when you launch it.

```
svn diff | subl &
```

The **`&`** makes all the difference.

Comment: Thank you. That does exactly what I want. I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: I noticed some strange output after closing the file in Sublime: `[1]+  Done                    ls -Gh | subl`. Does anyone know what to do about that?

Comment: That the shell's process control telling you that a background process (sublime in this case) has finished/terminated. If you wrapped the command in parens it will (should) eliminate the notification: (svn diff | subl &)

Comment: Thanks, @SuperMagic. Now it really does exactly what I want, as far as I can tell.